# BOX JAVA SDK: 1.0.0: Adding proxy settings to to BoxAPIConnection

Tags: java, proxy, box

Im currently evaluating updating our Box client code from box-java-sdk-v2 to the latest version 1.0.0 and don't see any way to add a proxy to a BoxAPIConnection.

http://opensource.box.com/box-java-sdk/javadoc/com/box/sdk/BoxAPIConnection.html

Here is a snippet of how the v2 BoxClient worked:

```
//add a proxy if configured
IBoxRESTClient restClient = new BoxRESTClient() {
        @Override
        public HttpClient getRawHttpClient() {
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(config.getProxyHost(), config.getProxyPort());
            DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                    .build();
            return httpclient;
        }
};

if(config.isUseProxy()){
        logger.info("Configuring Box SDK client to use a proxy: " + config.getProxyHost() + " : " + config.getProxyPort());
        boxClient = new BoxClient(config.getBoxClientToken(), config.getBoxClientSecretToken(), null, null, restClient, (new BoxConfigBuilder()).build());
}else{
        logger.info("Configuring Box SDK client with NO proxy");
        boxClient = new BoxClient(config.getBoxClientToken(), config.getBoxClientSecretToken(), null, null, (new BoxConfigBuilder()).build());
}
// actually do the authentication of our Box client
boxClient.authenticate(boxToken);
```

Comment: I am  struggling in the same problem.How to add proxy to boxapiconnection in box java sdk?

Answer (score 0):

There are methods, setProxy(), SetProxyUsername() in BoxAPIConnection for this use case. 
Try using them instead.